# How arrows are damaging aircraft canopy here but previously not?

Tags: avatar

In previous battle between Navi and Sky people, arrows did just
scars on aircraft canopy:

[image]

But in final battle, arrows penetrate aircraft canopy here:

[image]

Comment: The second arrow is much larger. Presumably it's a battle arrow intended to pierce armour instead of the normal arrows that the Na'vi carry around for general hunting and such

Comment: Indeed, looks more like something fired from a ballista

Comment: The arrows in the first attack were coming from the ground/low branches of the tree below the aircraft. They'd lose a lot of force fighting gravity. In the second attack they are coming from above, (no gravity loss, fired from a shooter diving toward the aircraft (More speed=More force) I would guesstimate they have 2-3x the force of the ones fired in the first attack. Also the first attack was a surprise, the Navi probably used any arrow they had on hand to shoot. The second was a planned battle, they probably used heaver arrows with harder tips.